# How do I convert MySQL queries written in Ruby to SQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby

How do I convert MySQL queries written in Ruby to SQL?

This is how it is:

```
create_table "academic_details", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "registration_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `academic_details` (
  `registration_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` DATETIME,
  `updated_at` DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

run `rake db:structure:dump`, all the table definitions will be generated in db/structure.sql

Comment: for that i need to install compiler and mysql everything, is there any short cut?? because i know 0 about ruby...

Comment: are you using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @ManjunathHegde you need only the mysql driver and the mysql gem, I guess and rails of course

Answer (score 0):

The following command will get you mostly there:

```
rake db:structure:dump
```

This will create a file called `structure.sql` in your Rails app's `db` folder, which contains the `create table` sql queries which you're looking for, along with `create index` queries.

But, I say *mostly there* because you will need to manually add each table's `ENGINE`, `DEFAULT CHARSET`, and `COLLATION`.

More information on the rake command at the link below.  Do a search in the page for `db:structure:dump`:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll highly recommend looking at [the Sequel gem](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net). It's an "ORM" which acts as an interface between Ruby and any number of databases.

The big advantage is you can easily write a query in Sequel's DSL, and it will take care of all the specifics for talking to that particular DBM. If you need to convert to another vendor's database engine, such as PostgreSQL, Oracle or SQLServer, it's a simple matter of converting your connection string, and building the tables. You don't have to rewrite any queries at all.

In particular, it supports ["migrations"](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html) which are an easy way to incrementally define your database. Yours would look something like:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
  create_table :academic_details |t|
    primary_key :id
    Integer :registration_id
    Datetime :created_at
    Datetime :updated_at
  end

  down do
    drop_table :academic_details
  end
end
```

Read through the documentation and the [README page](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html). It's a great tool.